# Is there a way to integrate Google spreadsheets with an application in windows CE 7.0

Tags: windows, google-sheets, embedded, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

My motive is to fetch data of an application, say application stores information of product, its name and price, now i want this to view in google spreadsheet, much like integrating the Google spreadsheet and application. 
Is there a way to make it work or should I bang my head to get some other idea.

Thank you

Comment: I think that this question is too broad.